# About Pattern Match string using regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have txt file like following:

```
31.03.15 15:46:42 Broker=Varengold Bank AG Server=VarengoldBank-Demo AccNo=1234673584 Curr=EUR IsDemo=TRUE Digits=5 Pair=EURUSD Balance=0 |
31.03.15 15:46:42 MT0 Datacenter: |
31.03.15 15:46:42 ;MT[0] Bid 1,07394|
Logfile rotation initiated.|
```

I use `StreamReader.ReadLine()` to read data.

How can I use Regex to match data like this:

```
Ex: 31.03.15 15:46:42 MT0 Datacenter: |
Datetime = 31.03.15 15:46:42
Content=MT0 Datacenter: (remove "|")
with second line:
Datetime=31.03.15 15:46:42
Content=MT[0] Bid 1,07394 (remove ";|")
```

and the last is:
Datetime=
Content=Logfile rotation initiated.

Comment: where is your regex?

Comment: Could you please clarify? What are the exact criteria? Please post your code.

Comment: Construct your regex & then use `MatchCollection `. If you are asking how to use regex then visit http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_regular_expressions.htm

Comment: I want to ask about the pattern of regex.

Comment: You should let us know exactly *what* you want to match in the above input text, what pattern you need. If you just want to match exact several lines, you should use `.ReadToEnd()` and then use a regex to match this multiple line input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?:\d\d[\.]){2}\d\d (?:\d\d[:]){2}\d\d
```

will match the Datetime. For the content, you can have this:

```
[A-Za-z].+(?=[|])
```

This will take your line starting with an alphabetical character and ending with |.

Comment: The . is regarded as "any character". You need to escape it. Furthermore, it would be a good practice to use groups here

Comment: Datetime is ok, but about the content. sometime it after ";" and before "|"

Comment: Good point, thank you Georg. I will change this a bit.

Comment: @thehiep8x see the new regex

Comment: @Docteur can you explain ".+" and "*"?

Comment: The .+ means to match any character any number of time. The positive lookup `(?=[|])` will look for the |, but not include it.
Where is a *?

Comment: @Docteur So, what different between ".+" and "*"?

Comment: Sorry, mixed up. * is match from zero to n times (so if there is no otther character than the first, use that). + is one or more.